# Always Override the Contents of a Particular Subfolder

Tags: git

I have a git directory that contains 5 subfolders:

- My Project

  - Folder 1
  - Folder 2
  - Folder 3
  - Folder 4
  - *Folder 5*

The contents of folders one through four are allowed to be merged as usual. However, all of the contents in folder 5 must be overridden every time, not merged. No exceptions. Is there a way that I can modify the .gitattributes file to make this happen automatically?

Comment: Why must it be always overridden?

Comment: The files inside are proprietary and will not work properly in their native software if merged with another version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** - A couple thoughts I should add...

Another down-side to the "merge driver" approach is that I'm pretty sure you'd have to (partially) set it up individually in each clone of the repo, because I don't think the necessary config settings will be shared by push/fetch operations.  You could avoid that problem by using the default `binary` merge driver (although in that case, instead of "trying to do the right thing", git will just tell you there's a conflict any time a file-level merge would be needed in that directory; and this is still a file-by-file solution).

And that also points out this is a client-enforced scheme; if you need a hard policy on this, a server-side post-receive hook might be more suitable.  (Actually a combination of the two might be worth considering, to avoid accidental violations going uncaught long enough to become hard to fix.)  But the trouble is, defining the hook to distinguish a "bad" push from a "good" one in this case might not be so simple.

---

**Original Response**

The best I can think of would be to define a custom merge driver and use `.gitattributes`.  But it's not great - there could be some cases where the behavior isn't what you might expect.

Suppose you've got

```
R --- A <--(master)
 \
  B <--(branch)
```

and `A` and `B` each modify a file in your subdirectory.  So merging `branch` into `master`, if you want to keep the version from `B` (override from the branch) you would do the following.  (I'll revisit these steps with how you'd keep the `master` version shortly...)

In the repository configuration, define a custom merge type

```
[merge "theirs"]
        name = Keep 'Their' Version
        driver = cp %B %A
```

Then create a `.gitattributes` file in your work tree root, which you'll add and commit

```
Folder5/* merge=theirs
```

(or, if there are sub-directories that also need this treatment,

```
Folder5/**/* merge=theirs
```

instead.)

Now any time you merge a branch that includes changes to files in `Folder5`, those changes will be taken; any changes (conflicting or otherwise) to the same file in "our" branch (e.g. the `master` side of "merging `branch` into `master`") will be ignored.

**HOWEVER**, if a specific file is *unchanged* in `branch`, then any changes in `master` will be taken.  And this is determined on a file-by-file basis; so if `master` modifies `Folder5/file1` and `Folder5/file2`, but `branch` only modifies `Folder5/file1`, then the merge result will have the `master` version of `file2` and the `branch` version of `file1`.

Also, if you ever have "long-lived" branches and do "backwards merges" to keep them from falling out of sync, the (potentially silent) default for the backwards merge would be to override the changes in the branch with changes from `master`.

So depending on your workflow, this could make git "do the right thing" by default more often, but it could also create some cases where it does something unexpected and harmful.

**What if you wanted to keep the master version?**

Well, then you could define the merge driver a bit differently

```
[merge "ours"]
        name = Keep 'Our' Version
        driver = true
```

(You're really just doing a no-op with this driver; in a previous version I suggested `touch %A` as "relatively harmless", but this avoids even tweaking the timestamp.)

And of course the `.gitattributes` entry would say `merge=ours`

Again, this only takes effect when a file is actually subject to a merge.  So it means that changes on `branch` will be ignored *if the same file has changes on `master`*.

On the plus side (I guess), "backwards merges" into long-lived branches might be less troublesome in this case.

Comment: FYI, you can just use `true` as the no-op driver - there is no need to update the date-stamp. The fact that the driver is only run if there are changes on "both sides", though, is (I think) the main problem here.

Comment: Hmm. Well, you're right about `true`. I'm not sure if it matters much (since normally you wouldn't expect a merge to preserve timestamps) but I'll update accordingly.  As I noted, the "non-merging" cases are certainly what gives me the most pause with this approach; but figured I might as well provide it in case OP feels it's better than nothing for his use case, especially because I simply don't know a better way to approximate what is requested